# Touch sequence password in iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

[image]

I am thinking of making a password sequence for my app, like that in dot protection. Do I have to learn the whole **open Gl es** for it, or it can be done with `(void) touchesMoved` and then checking each button is in a `CGrectIntersects()`?

I am thinking of giving the `CGrectInterscts` a try, but after I saw that the dot protection app technique somehow doesn't **let user move to 2 from 1** (see screenshot).

I think this type of complex mechanism is something that cannot be done with that way.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's definitely something that you can achieve with touchesmoved!
I've done something like this myself and I think you should do it exactly as you said, simply track each move with the touchesbegan (and touchesmoved and touchesended) and use the CGRectIntersect with your uiimageviews or coordinates, however you want to do it. It's possible!

Comment: how did you block the movement form 1 to 2 in the above screenshot?

Comment: well you probably save all the dots that are already touched, so when a CGRectintersect returns true, just check whether the dot is an adjacent one or not, shouldn't be too hard :)

Comment: @Shubhank, BobDev: Note that SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. In general, ask questions in questions (not comments) and respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a post should be understandable without reading comments. For another, comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. If you want to discuss something, use [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to roll your own implementation, you could use some libraries that already exist like [ALUnlockPatternView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/alunlockpatternview) which looks like this:

[image]

Or [Android Pattern Lock](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/android-pattern-lock-on-iphone) which looks like this:

[image]